# Is it possible to bind dependabot on releases from a specific Github repository?

Tags: github, dependabot, github-release

I'm working on a script who build docker image based on a github project.
My Dockerfile download release zip file from this repository and package in a Docker image.

So, I want to configure Dependabot to create PR automatically when a new release is publish.

Any idea ?